# WireCloud login with keystone: AuthStateForbidden at /complete/fiware/

Tags: fiware, keystone, fiware-wirecloud

When trying to login to WireCloud via Keystone with an user that already has WireCloud authorized the following error is displayed:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dashboard.example.com/complete/fiware/?state=pHFsTpzh7lhXKBiqkpZxSYOPpRi5w1ph&code=pxJSjgIqyAVAvHfP8xzFIkAmnCLtx6

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'wirecloud.commons',
 'compressor',
 'wirecloud.catalogue',
 'wirecloud.platform',
 'wirecloud.oauth2provider',
 'wirecloud.fiware',
 'social.apps.django_app.default')
Installed Middleware:
('wirecloud.commons.middleware.URLMiddleware',)



Traceback:

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  51.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py" in do_complete
  43.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in complete
  41.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  229.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in auth_complete
  375.         state = self.validate_state()

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in validate_state
  90.             raise AuthStateForbidden(self)

Exception Type: AuthStateForbidden at /complete/fiware/
Exception Value: Wrong state parameter given.
```

When you then try to log into WireCloud again with that user, so that the session from the Keyrock login is still active, it works fine. But why does this error get displayed?

And even worse: If a new user wants to sign up to WireCloud, after the login to Keystone, this error gets thrown:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://dashboard.example.com/complete/fiware/?state=4Ccx9THwAxUht3rXi3N3J9du1LTTOmcC&code=mZXx34K8ojV9RJiNiNtUuzc10HtoJU

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'wirecloud.commons',
 'compressor',
 'wirecloud.catalogue',
 'wirecloud.platform',
 'wirecloud.oauth2provider',
 'wirecloud.fiware',
 'social.apps.django_app.default')
Installed Middleware:
('wirecloud.commons.middleware.URLMiddleware',)



Traceback:

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/utils.py" in wrapper
  51.             return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/views.py" in complete
  28.                        redirect_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/actions.py" in do_complete
  43.         user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in complete
  41.         return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  229.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in auth_complete
  387.                             *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py" in wrapper
  229.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/oauth.py" in do_auth
  398.         return self.strategy.authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/strategies/django_strategy.py" in authenticate
  96.         return authenticate(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  74.             user = backend.authenticate(**credentials)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in authenticate
  82.         return self.pipeline(pipeline, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in pipeline
  85.         out = self.run_pipeline(pipeline, pipeline_index, *args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/base.py" in run_pipeline
  112.             result = func(*args, **out) or {}

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/pipeline/user.py" in create_user
  69.         'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/strategies/base.py" in create_user
  53.         return self.storage.user.create_user(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/storage/django_orm.py" in create_user
  60.         return cls.user_model().objects.create_user(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in create_user
  154.         return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in _create_user
  148.         user.save(using=self._db)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  74.         super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  708.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  736.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  820.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  859.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  95.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/opt/wc/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /complete/fiware/
Exception Value: FEHLER:  NULL-Wert in Spalte „last_login“ verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
DETAIL:  Fehlgeschlagene Zeile enthält (21, !mtZhl9gusVEPg4QTz80CbnY61pc7SxUF73AvtPu7, null, f, bi-demo, , , bi-demo@example.com, f, t, 2016-06-16 06:40:19.588666+00).
```

This indicates that some postgres constraints may be violated (we use postgres as db for WireCloud). It happens when an user that has not yet authorized WireCloud but is logged in to keystone tries to access WireCloud. Usually then the authorize page should get displayed but instead the error is thrown and the user is not created in the WireCloud Django admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate your first error, but taking into account your second error I can confirm that you have unapplied migrations for the `django-contrib-auth` django app.

Use `python manage.py migrate --list` for getting the list of applied or unapplied migrations. You should get something like this:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [ ] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [ ] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [ ] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
catalogue
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
default
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_add_related_name
 [X] 0003_alter_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_auto_20160423_0400
platform
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_auto_20160127_1143
 [X] 0003_remove_userworkspace_active
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

In your case, you are getting the second error because the `0005_alter_user_last_login_null` is not applied correctly (`django.contrib.auth` is listed as `auth`).

You can apply any pending migration using `python manage.py migrate` (if you prefer you can apply any pending migration for the `django.contrib.auth` app using `python manage.py migrate auth` instead).

The first error can also be related to unapplied migrations, but I cannot tell you what migration.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate --list` lists only empty boxes thus it looks like there are all migrations left to do. But upon calling `python manage.py migrate` I get the message `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR:  Relation „django_content_type“ already exists`.
Thus I dropped the whole db and tried the migration then. This way migration worked but when logging in the errors are the same.

Comment: It's strange because if the `0005_alter_user_last_login_null` is applied correctly, you cannot get `NOT NULL constraint failed: auth_user.last_login`  as this migration instructs the db to use a default value if the `last_login` column is `null`. Did you installed WireCloud by hand? did you installed WireCloud using docker? what DB are you using (postgres/mysql)?

Comment: We installed WireCloud by hand and use PostgreSQL as db. Might it come from the update of WireCloud? We installed a WireCloud version that still had `python manage.py syncdb` available and then updated.

Comment: Maybe, did you followed those [steps](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/stable/administration_guide/#upgrading-to-django-17)?

Comment: I don't know what the actuat problem was. But now we managed to set up wirecloud with keyrock and horizon and everything seems to work fine. Thank you very much for your support!